# AMQP : How worker will listen and execute automatically

Tags: php, rabbitmq, sendmail, amqp, worker

Implementing AMQP in PHP and making Email queue functionalities but stuck at How to worker file or function will call automatically?

If  putting worker's logic after my take getting executed. But not sure that way it gonna work!

```
require_once('php-amqplib-master/amqp.inc');

class sendMailToQueue
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->rabbitMQConf = array("host"=>"localhost","port"=>"5672","user"=>"guest","pass"=>"guest","virtualHost"=>"/");
    }

    function send($to,$subject,$text)
    {

        try {
            $conn = new AMQPConnection($this->rabbitMQConf['host'], 
            $this->rabbitMQConf['port'],
            $this->rabbitMQConf['user'],
            $this->rabbitMQConf['pass']);

            $channel = $conn->channel();
            $channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false);
            $mailData = array("to"=>$to,
            "subject"=>$subject,
            "text"=>$text);

            $mailDataToJson = json_encode($mailData);
            $msg = new AMQPMessage($mailDataToJson, array('content_type' => 'text/plain'));
            $channel->basic_publish($msg, '','task_queue');

            $callback = function($msg){
                $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

                //my send mail logic comes here

                if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                    echo "Email sent";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Email sending failed";
                }
            };    

            $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
            $channel->basic_consume('task_queue', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

            while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
                $channel->wait();
            }

            $channel->close();
            $conn->close();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Something went wrong ".$e->getMessage();
        }
   }
}
$mailSender = new sendMailToQueue();
$to = "user@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a text message";
$text = "I show you how deep the rabbit-hole goes";
if ( $mailSender->send($to, $subject, $text ) ) {
    echo "Mail sent to queue"; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are using a very old version of php-amqplib. See https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib

Comment: Why are you publishing and consuming on the same file?

Comment: Perhaps take a look here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html

Comment: Actually i was thinking that to get worker execute i need to call it every time , but got to know that at the time of deployment just needs to start that worker once queue declared it will execute automatically.thanks @old_sound for your help but :)

Comment: Yes, you just run workers once, and they stay listening for incoming messages